# How to write a string to a notebook

Tags: notebooks

**Apparently I'm having a problem even asking my question correctly and getting my edits to appear, so I'm asking the question once again.  Hopefully it will go through and I'll get a specific answer.**

HyperCard was a great Apple program which I used to take notes on what I read. I accumulated 100+ megaBytes of (mostly) text. The last Apple computer which could run it uses the PowerPC G5. Newer Apples won't run HyperCard as their memory management is different. Nothing lasts forever, and I'm down to my last Apple PowerPC G5 hence the reason for the move.

The HyperCard data is in the form of several types of cards (xref, glossary, index, topics). I wrote programs in HyperCard to move their data and data about them (e.g.metadata) into text files, which are basically a list of strings. These are loaded into the variable iData[] in a Mathematica program which allows me to access each string.

Here is the data and metadata on just two index cards, loaded into a Mathematica noteBook.

```
In[77]:= iData = 
  Import [ 
  "/Users/lewisrobinson/Desktop/Hypercard Xref/  IndexCards  100  to  \
 101", "lines" ] 


Out[77]= {"Total Number of Cards =  2 ", "Begin  card \"I2582705\" ",     \
 "card id 2582705 ", "5 hydroxylysine ", "No Topic Assigned ", "No \
  Topic Identifier ", "3 ", "\"Structure \" ", "1850661    \"glossary\" \
  ", "\"Deficiency in type VI Ehlers Danlos syndrome\" ", "1048186    \
  \"Xref\" ", "\"Lysyl hydroxylase\" ", "2927558    \"Xref\" ", "End  \
  card \"I2582705\" ", "Begin  card \"I5074462\" ", "card id 5074462 ",    \
 "5 methoxy Tryptophan (5MTP) ", "Serotonin ", "t239 ", "1 ", "\"An \
 endogenous anti-inflammatory agent\" ", "2105283    \"Xref\" ", "End  \
  card \"I5074462\" "}
```

Here is the sort of manipulation I do on iData[]

```
 In[78]:= iData[[1]] 


 Out[78]= "Total Number of Cards =  2 "
```

In[90]:= (* Now mimic CardManipulation10.nb *)
numCardsS = StringExtract [ data[[1]], 6]

```
 Out[90]= "2"


 In[91]:= 
 numIndexCardsI = ToExpression [numIndexCardsS]

 
 Out[91]= 2
```

There is a lot of error checking at each step -- example

```
 If [ IntegerQ  [ numIndexCardsI], Null, showIndexCardVariables [] ]
```

iDataLN is an integer pointing to a particular string in iData[] Here is one such example of its use

```
  In[106]:= iCardTitle = iData [[iDataLN]]

  Out[106]= "5 hydroxylysine "
```

There is a lot more of this sort of thing as I march through iData[], with many strings given names like iCardTitle etc. etc.

But here is the nub of my question

I went to the File menu of Mathematica and chose new notebook and then saved it as Index.nb and then opened it.

What I want to do is write the string "5 hydroxylysine " to Index.nb

How do I do this? I'm embarrassed to be asking such a simple question, but until I can write strings like this into notebooks of my choice my programming has ground to a halt.  I realize that this is similar to a question I've asked previously, but the devil appears to be in the details about how files are named and where they are, and Index.nb is a new file in the Mathematica environment.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to write to text files, not notebooks.

Comment: Regarding your preamble, yes you’re having difficulty. This is very difficult to understand.

Comment: If you’ve opened index.nb and you want to write something to it, that’s what the keyboard is for.

Comment: You have a text file with data. You have a new notebook. You read and process the data on the notebook. You save the notebook as index.nb. You open the notebook. And….. what? More processing of text file? Manually adding a string to the text file? Reading a different text file? Writing to a file?

Comment: Since ultimately this seems to stem from an attempt to port your HyperCard stacks, have you considered [LiveCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveCode) or [SuperCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperCard)?

Comment: You might start by checking the documentation for OpenWrite[], WriteString[] (or Write[]), and Close[]. Since your output is already stored in iCardTitle, something like WriteString[channel/file,iCardTitle] is what you probably want, where the first argument is the file name or channel/stream from the OpenWrite command.

Comment: lericr: Thanks for trying to help.  The variable iCardTitle is a string from iData[[]] which is sitting in another notebook (called iCardManipulation) containing the code above.   I want code to write this string to the second notebook Index.nb. Your last comment looks to be exactly what I want -- how do I find channel/file for Index.nb?

Comment: I missed the fact that your notebook was already open. The OpenWrite command opens a file for writing, and locks it, so you don't want to have it already open. The command returns a "stream" or "channel" object, which you pass to OpenWrite along with your data. When you're done with all your writes, use Close and pass the stream/channel object to release the resource, to unlock your file.

Comment: Also, I recommend testing this on a new file, to avoid the risk of trashing anything in your existing notebook. And i agree with the remarks made about using an ordinary text file in place of a notebook. Notebooks are general purpose, designed to hold images/text/etc. and organized into cells. For writing strings, a text file will suit your needs equally well. If you wish, you can Import the file into a notebook once you've processed your data.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the earlier comment and can't edit. stream=OpenWrite[<path to file>], WriteString[stream,string], repeated as needed, then Close[stream].

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**  An easy way

```
NotebookWrite[First@Notebooks["Index.nb"],
  Cell["5 hydroxylysine", "Text"]]
```

**Original:**

This may not be the best way, but it seems to work for me.

```
nbList = Notebooks[];

target = First@Select[nbList,
    MemberQ[NotebookInformation[#], "Index.nb", ∞] &];

NotebookWrite[target,
    Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"5 hydroxylysine"}]], "Text"]
  ];
```

The first line of code makes a list of all open notebooks.  When I click on Window in the toolbar, I see 3 notebooks listed.  One of them is Index.nb, but it is not selected.  The first line of code returns a list of NotebookObjects.

The second line of code detects which NotebookObject in the list has the filename "Index.nb".  If the target notebook is open, the variable `target` will be it, as a NotebookObject.

The third line writes the string to a new cell in the target notebook.  The new cell has the style "Text".  Other cell styles are listed when I click on the Format->Style in the main toolbar.  The new text cell goes in wherever the cursor in the target notebook happens to be.  I recommend reading every word of the documentation on `NotebookWrite` and `NotebookApply`.

For more examples, I would search this forum for NotebookWrite or BoxData.  For more information I would (also maybe try to) read the [low level notebook programming guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LowLevelNotebookProgramming.html).